# ¿Cómo permito que puedan ejecutar una aplicación web alojada en una carpeta?

Tags: .htaccess

La definición del archivo .htaccess no me permite ejecutar aplicaciones web que desarrollé y alojé dentro de CARPETAS del directorio htdocs en el servidor. 
¿Hay alguna instrucción que deba agregar o quitar?

Con este htaccess que muestro la WEB funciona bien pero si voy a una carpeta donde tengo alojada una aplicación independiente de la WEB, no me da permiso. Entiendo que ese htaccess está configurado para que funcione unas referencias de la WEB.

¿Me podrán dar una idea de que agregar o quitar?

Gracias de antemano.

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www/.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

RewriteRule "^fs/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$" files-nz/thumb/$2/$1$3  [L]
RewriteRule "^f/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$" files/thumb/$2/$1$3  [L]
RewriteRule "^fd/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)/(.*)" files/download/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^es/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^noticias(\/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ index.php [L,QSA,E=APP_MODULE:admin]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)?$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA,E=APP_MODULE:admin]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: y no es mejor definir la url en virtualhost?

Comment: Ignoro como. Quisiera si pueden responder sobre el problema planteado.